# Angularjs - how to share videos to available social media

Tags: json, angularjs

I am developing mobile app first time using angularjs.I am fetching data from json file using below code,

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="GetVideosFiles">

<ul ng-repeat=" x in GetData.videos ">
<li>example</li>
    <li><h1>{{ x.Title }}</h1></li>
    <li>{{x.Description}}</li><br><br>
    <li><a ng-href="{{ x.Url }}">Watch video</a></li>  
    <li><button ng-click="">Share</button></li>
</ul>


</div>

<script type="text/javascript">


var app=angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("GetVideosFiles",GetVideosFiles);
function GetVideosFiles($scope,$http){

     $scope.GetData = [];
    $http.get("VideoFile.json")
    .success(function(rsp){
        //alert(rsp);

        $scope.GetData = rsp;
        });
        }

</script>
```

VideoFile.json :

```
{ 
    "videos": [{ 
        "Title": "Windmill", 
        "Description": "What are wind mills? Are they giant fans? How do they work?", 
        "Url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zrp0RC3XTpw" 
    }, { 
        "Title": "Race Car", 
        "Description": "Yeah, we know that your kid loves his cars", 
        "Url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAteCGxrCSo" 
    }, { 
        "Title": "Blow Painting", 
        "Description": "The gentle wind has many an artist", 
        "Url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKs3nw7YcR8" 
    }, , { 
        "Title": "Dreamcatcher", 
        "Description": "The wind turned naughty and blown the pieces of Dream catcher all over 
the hose", 
        "Url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbgZ­uDAmAM" 
    }] 
}
```

when i click the share button that should display available social media to share the specific video.

I am new to angularjs so please someone guide me that how to achieve this one ?

sample code would be appreciable.

Comment: So basically you want to toggle a `div` containing share links for video `x`?

Comment: @Peter yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

This ng-click will toggle the value of `showShare`:

```
<li><button ng-click="showShare=!showShare">Share</button></li>
```

Then add a `<span>` or some other element with an `ng-show` like:

```
<span ng-show="showShare">
     <a>Some share link</a>
</span>
```

This span will only be shown when showShare is true. (The `<span>` goes inside or after the `<li>` shown above)